# asyncio.create_task() is not running asynchronously in async view function

Tags: django, python-asyncio

I'm creating an async function to upload a video. The goal is to run the video upload asynchronously in the background without making the user wait. The user will be redirected to another page while the video is uploading.

Following instructions in Python's asyncio docs, I'm using `create_task()` as that seems to be the simplest solution.

In the following code, it works but it is not running asynchronously. `HttpResponseRedirect` is not running until after the video is fully uploaded.

I also inserted 2 lines to check whether `upload_video()` is running asynchronously and it is. `print('before')` and `print('after')` are both printed to the console *before* the `upload_video` function completes. However, the final `HttpResponseRedirect()` does not run until all the code has been executed.

```
async def my_async_func(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        video = request.FILES['video']
        print('before')
        asyncio.create_task(upload_video(video))
        print('after')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(... somewhere)


async def upload_video(video):
    ...
```

Basically despite all the async syntax & logic I wrote, the function is still running like a typical synchronous django view function.

Why is this? What do I need to change to make `upload_video()` run asynchronously and return `HttpResponseRedirect()` without waiting?

P.S. I also tried replacing `create_task()` with `ensure_future()` but it gave me the same result - the videos uploads but not asynchronously.

Comment: Does saving a reference to the task (not in the view) work?

Comment: @pigrammer thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it following the syntax in the docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks), adding the task to a `background_tasks = set()` and discarding it when it's complete. Unfortunately it still returned the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Use Django's event loop instead of the default one:

```py
tasks = set()

async def my_async_func(request):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        video = request.FILES['video']
        print('before')
        task = loop.create_task(upload_video(video)
        tasks.add(task)
        tasks.add_done_callback(tasks.discard)
        print('after')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(... somewhere)


async def upload_video(video):
    ...
```

Also, make sure you [save a reference to the task so that it doesn't disappear](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task).